# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SearchBar in React Native

Tags: react-native

I got an error called "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SearchBar". I tried to check for syntax error and run the app again. But the same error appeared. How can I rectify it? Thanks.

This is my SearchScreen.js file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const SearchScreen = () => {
  const [term, setTerm] = useState('')
  
  return (
    <View>
        <SearchBar
          term={term}
          onTermChange={(newTerm) => setTerm(newTerm)} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default SearchScreen;
```

This is my SearchBar.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { EvilIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const SearchBar = ({ term, onTermChange }) => {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.background}>
            <EvilIcons style={styles.icon} name="search" />
            <TextInput
                value={term}
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Search"
                onChangeText={newTerm => onTermChange(newTerm)} />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 6,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: 35,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 15
  }
});
```

Comment: You have forgotten to export SearchBar component that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just did. However, it's still showing the same error. Apparently, it is pointing to my <view> line of my SearchScreen.js file.

Comment: How do you export and import your `SearchBar` lately?

Comment: in SearchScreen.js you forgot to import SearchBar; and in SearchBar.js you forgot export default!!

Comment: @RedwanNassim Yes, you are right ;)